# Download of file via jQuery works in IIS Express but not when deployed to IIS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2012, extjs

I have solution that uses ExtJS library to post data via jQuery to the backend in MVC 3.0.
Now, when I start the solution in VS 2012 download works as expected. As soon As I deploy my solution to full IIS 8.5 file doesn't download and throws 500 as internal server error.
I have stripped backend code so that just serves file that is already in target folder on server, but even that doesn't work.
I have tried to set permissions for IIS_USRS group on domain giving them full control but it still fails.
Anyone have a clue what could be the cause (web.config is deployed to IIS from IIS Express) using Publish option in VS2012.

Thanks

Comment: There are multitude of reasons, nothing we can help you with if you don't provide more input, unfortunately. Please check which user the Application pool runs under. Can you enable custom errors so you get a more concise error message than just "Error 500"?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using log4net to capture any error on the backend side and log is empty. I will try to enable Tracing but if I understand correctly deployment from IIS Express to IIS should be straightforward. (I don't know many details about IIS just from developer perspective)

Comment: An empty log is suspicious in itself; to make sure log4net is not the issue, you should put one special log message into the log.

Comment: Done. Still the same. :(

Comment: Log4net does not log any errors that occurs on server side automatically . This is feature that [Elmah](https://elmah.github.io/) does. As far as I know with log4net you should manually log messages in your code.

Comment: I have installed Elmah and it is included to intercept errors. However still it shows no error when I go to his .axd url